# Moving Files with PHP that have been uploaded

Tags: php, upload

I've gone through some of the questions, but haven't found an answer to my question so here it goes.

I've written a stereotypical script for uploading small files. The script works, and the file is uploaded to the server. However, I can't get it to upload it to move to the right subfolder.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " MB<br>";

}
if (file_exists("/enhstudios/clients/media/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "/enhstudios/clients/media/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

  }
?>
```

The error I get is:
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/enhstudios/clients/july.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/waloraweb013/b1311/moo.enhstudios/enhstudios/clients/fileuploadcode.php on line 20

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpkfxGLm' to '/enhstudios/clients/july.jpg' in /hermes/waloraweb013/b1311/moo.enhstudios/enhstudios/clients/fileuploadcode.php on line 20

Permissions for this directory are set at 777.

Where have I gone wrong? I've tried all different combos of subdirectories and still can't get it to upload to the right one.

Comment: Have you tried with `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/enhstudios/clients/media/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);` ?

Comment: Yes, and unfortunately I get the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't mix the `/hermes/waloraweb013/b1311/moo.enhstudios/enhstudios/clients` and the `/enhstudios/clients/` directories?

I think you would like to move to the longer one, but the second arguments first / makes it an absoulte path.

You can add there the full path, or you can try to remove the first /. (This relativisation works only if the document root is `/hermes/waloraweb013/b1311/moo.enhstudios/`)

Comment: I would avoid ever relying on relative paths and the "current directory" in a PHP script. If you want something relative to the document root, use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, or relative to the current file with `__DIR__` / `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Wow, thank you Lajos. For some reason that was the only thing I didn't try. I thought(assumed) that it would be the same path, that /enhstudios/clients/ was a shortened version.

You know what they say about assumptions...thanks again. And if I had the rep, I'd upvote the answer.